# AWS DMS. Endpoint connection fails in replication instance (Error: 1020912)

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Create an endpoint, associated with my AWS-DMS instance, to connect to an On-premises SQL Server database and the test connections fails!!!

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect  Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HYT00 NativeError: 0 Message: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

Comment: Can you please share the resolution if you found it? I am facing the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: @S.Nori 

In my case, I deleted the instance because it was on a different network segment than the VPC to access my On-premises Sql
When creating the new instance, I made sure it was on the same segment.

Note: it is also important to check the SQL instance port and firewall rule

Answer (score 3):

make sure both use the same VPC plus security group

to use same VPC

create new subnet group under `Subnet groups` using same VPC for your On-premises Sql

Answer (score 1):

I have this error when I was doing the databases migration cross-account.

If you have a source database in the source Account and a target database on the target Account.

First, you should setup the vpc peering connection (Note, VPC CIDR shouldn't overlapping.)  Then you update the Route table for each other vpc cidr range.

Second, On the Target account, set up the source and target endpoint, replication instance.  When you set up the replication instance, make sure it stays with the target endpoint VPC.

Third, update the source and target account database security group inbound rules,  to allow the replication instance private IP address with the database port.

Then you should be able to test the source and target endpoint with the replication instance connection without this error.